# Haar measure $\tau$-additive?

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups, haar-measure

I'm reading some results from Measure Theory Volume 4 by D.H. Fremlin, and I'm stuck on something.

---

This is pulled out of one of his lemmas (stated more generally for topological groups):

A Haar measure $\mu$ on a locally compact group $G$ is strictly positive.

---

The proof is quite short:

It is sufficient to show that $\mu$ is positive on non-empty open sets containing 1.

Suppose for a contradiction that $U$ is an open set containing $1$ and $\mu(U) = 0$.

Then $G = \bigcup\limits_{x\in G}xU$, and since $G$ is $\tau$-additive, $\mu(G) = 0$, a contradiction.

---

I assume that $\tau$-additive means that $\mu(\bigcup_{\alpha\in J}E_{\alpha}) \leq \sum\limits_{\alpha\in J}\mu(E_{\alpha})$ is this correct?

If so, then why do Haar measures have this property.  If not what does it really mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $\tau$-additivity is given in volume 4 of Fremlin's "Measure Theory", 411C (page 14):

> If $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ is a measure space and $T$ a topology on $X$, we say that $\mu$ is $\tau$-additive (also "$\tau$-regular") if for every upper-directed family $(U_i)_{i \in I} \subseteq T \cap \Sigma$ with $\bigcup _{i \in I} U_i \in \Sigma$ we have
>
> $$\mu \left( \bigcup _{i \in I} U_i \right) = \sup _{i \in I} \mu (U_i) \ .$$
>
> ("Upper-directed" means that $I$ is an [upper-directed set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set) and for $i \le j$ we have $U_i \subseteq U_j$.)

It is proven in 411E that if $\mu$ is inner-regular with respect to the compact subsets (definition given in 411B) then it is $\tau$-additive.

It is shown in 441E (page 274) that every locally-compact Hausdorff topological group has left and right Haar measures, and these are Radon measures (therefore inner-regular with respect to the compact subsets, therefore $\tau$-additive).

Your question is about exercise 441X.h.(i) and lemma 442A.(a). Consider $U$ an open neighbourhood of $1$ and assume $\mu (U) = 0$ (with $\mu$ a left Haar measure); translation invariance implies that $\mu (gU) = 0$ for all $g \in G$ . Let $I = \{F \subseteq G \mid F \text{ is finite}\}$ and notice that $I$ is upper-directed under the inclusion of subsets. For $F = \{g_1, \dots, g_n\} \in I$ define $U_F = g_1 U \cup \dots \cup g_n U$. Notice that the family $(U_F)_{F \in I}$ is upper-directed, therefore the $\tau$-additivity of $\mu$ implies (using that trivially $G = \bigcup _{F \in G} U_F$)

$$\mu (G) = \mu \left( \bigcup _{F \in I} U_F \right) = \sup _{F \in I} \mu (U_F) = \sup _{n \ge 1, \ \{g_1, \dots, g_n\} \in I} \mu (g_1 U \cup \dots \cup g_n U) \le \\
\le \sup _{n \ge 1, \ \{g_1, \dots, g_n\} \in I} \underbrace {(\mu (g_1 U) + \dots + \mu (g_n U))} _{0 + \dots + 0} = 0 \ ,$$

which is not possible since $\mu$ is assumed non-trivial by definition.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what $\tau$-additive means, but if $G$ is a locally compact Hausdorff abelian group and $\mu$ is a left Haar measure, then $\mu(U)\neq 0$ for $U$ a non-empty open subset of $G$, and the proof is almost what you've written (except, again, I don't know what is meant by $\tau$-additive). Remember that Haar measures are non-zero by definition. They are also inner regular on open sets. So suppose $\mu(U)=0$. Then, by left invariance, $\mu(gU)=0$ for all $g\in G$. Now, if $K$ is a compact subset of $G$, then $K$ is covered by finitely many translates of $gU$ of $U$ (here we use that $U$ is non-empty). So $\mu(K)=0$ by sub-additivity. Finally, by inner regularity on opens, $\mu(G)$ is equal to the supremum of $\mu(K)$ as $K$ ranges over the compact subsets of $G$. But this supremum is $0$ by what we've just shown, contrary to the assumption that $\mu\neq 0$.

EDIT: Assuming the set $J$ in your inequality is supposed to be countable, then this is countable sub-additivity (or I guess just sub-additivity) of $\mu$, and every measure has this property. I guess now that I think about it, the way ``$\tau$-additivity" is being invoked seems to be some sort of extension of countable sub-additivity to collections of sets which might not be countable (since the union in the proof cited might not be a countable one). I don't know why this property holds for Haar measures. So I guess my answer doesn't really address the question, although the proof I've given does show that one need not resort to $\tau$-additivity, whatever it is, so I will leave it for now, but will delete it if the OP requests it.

Comment: This answer is better. :)

Thanks very much!

Comment: A topological measure is said to be $\tau$-additive if $\mu(\bigcup_{j \in J} U_j) = \sup_{j \in J} \mu(U_j)$ whenever $(U_j)_{j \in J}$ is a *directed* family of open sets. As you suspected, it's a strengthened version of $\sigma$-additivity. It's a technical condition many important measures share and it allows for dealing with nets instead of sequences in certain circumstances. It is not hard to show that a measure which is inner regular with respect to compact sets is $\tau$-additive, so on a formal level, using $\tau$-additivity is using a weaker assumption than inner regularity. (@Kyle)

Comment: Dear @Martin, Thanks for explaining that!

Comment: I second that!!  Thanks!

Comment: @KeenanKidwell : I think the idea for the proof that Haar measure are $\tau$-additive is contained in your answer, I'm still working it out.